# How to sort map's values?

Tags: dart

Can someone give me a hint? I want to sort a map's values by the length of the lists.

```
var chordtypes = {
  "maj": [0, 4, 7],
  "M7": [0, 4, 7, 11],
  "m7": [0, 3, 7, 10],
  "6": [0, 4, 7, 9],
  "9": [0, 4, 7, 10, 14],
  "sus2": [0, 2, 7],
  "sus4": [0, 5, 7],
  "omit3": [0, 7],
  "#5": [0, 4, 8],
  "+7b9#11": [0, 4, 8, 10, 13, 18],
  "+9": [0, 4, 8, 10, 14]
};
```

Comment: So you want to be "+7b9#11" to be the first element? I hardly think this is possible with a raw map in Dart.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A function that does sort a Map of List on their length.

```
import 'dart:collection';

/// sorts the ListMap (== A Map of List<V>) on the length
/// of the List values.
LinkedHashMap sortListMap(LinkedHashMap map) {
    List mapKeys = map.keys.toList(growable : false);
    mapKeys.sort((k1, k2) => map[k1].length - map[k2].length);
    LinkedHashMap resMap = new LinkedHashMap();
    mapKeys.forEach((k1) { resMap[k1] = map[k1] ; }) ;        
    return resMap;
}
```

result for :

```
var res = sortListMap(chordtypes);
print(res);
```

==>

```
{ omit3: [0, 7], 
  maj: [0, 4, 7], 
  sus2: [0, 2, 7], 
  sus4: [0, 5, 7], 
  #5: [0, 4, 8], 
  M7: [0, 4, 7, 11], 
  m7: [0, 3, 7, 10], 
  6: [0, 4, 7, 9], 
  9: [0, 4, 7, 10, 14], 
  +9: [0, 4, 8, 10, 14], 
  +7b9#11: [0, 4, 8, 10, 13, 18] }
```

Comment: It would be better to use a `LinkedHashMap` for `resMap` because it guarantees that it iterates keys in insertion order.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : I'd bet that the default implementation also iterates in insertion order, but far better than a bet... i updated my answer ! thanks.

Comment: Second though : Javascript is a messy language for sure. With Dart we can build a clean solutions, so we must. I updated to use only LinkedHashMap, and @marcus should only make use of this also, since the order of its map matters. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Using DART language:

Let's say you want to sort a Map with integer key and value of type Foo:

```
class Foo {
  int x; //it can be any type
}
```

So you can get the list of all the entries, sort them like a normal list and then rebuild the map:

```
Map<int, Foo> map = //fill map

var entries = map.entries.toList();
entries.sort((MapEntry<int, Foo> a, MapEntry<int, Foo> b) => a.value.x.compareTo(b.value.x));
map = Map<int, Foo>.fromEntries(entries);
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this could work for you:

```
Map chordtypes = {
  "maj": [0, 4, 7],
  "M7": [0, 4, 7, 11],
  "m7": [0, 3, 7, 10],
  "6": [0, 4, 7, 9],
  "9": [0, 4, 7, 10, 14],
  "sus2": [0, 2, 7],
  "sus4": [0, 5, 7],
  "omit3": [0, 7],
  "#5": [0, 4, 8],
  "+7b9#11": [0, 4, 8, 10, 13, 18],
  "+9": [0, 4, 8, 10, 14]
};

List keys = chordtypes.keys.toList();
keys.sort((k1, k2) {
  if(chordtypes[k1].length > chordtypes[k2].length)
    return -1;
  if(chordtypes[k1].length < chordtypes[k2].length)
    return 1;
  return 0;
});
keys.forEach((String k) {
  print('$k ${chordtypes[k]}');
});
```

Comment: the sort function (k1, k2) => ( chordtypes[k1].length - chordtypes[k2].length) will do the same, just shorter ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Building on @Leonardo Rignanese's answer. An extension function for a more functional approach:

```
extension MapExt<T, U> on Map<T, U> {
  Map<T, U> sortedBy(Comparable value(U u)) {
    final entries = this.entries.toList();
    entries.sort((a, b) => value(a.value).compareTo(value(b.value)));
    return Map<T, U>.fromEntries(entries);
  }
}
```

General usage:

```
foos.sortedBy((it) => it.bar);
```

Usage for OP:

```
final sortedChordtypes = chordtypes.sortedBy((it) => it.length);
```

Gist here: https://gist.github.com/nmwilk/68ae0424e848b9f05a8239db6b708390