# How to sort map value?

Tags: dart

I have this map:

```
var temp= { 
  'A' : 3,
  'B' : 1,
  'C' : 2
};
```

How to sort the values of the map (descending). I know, I can use temp.values.toList()..sort().

But I want to sort in context of the keys like this:

```
var temp= { 
  'B' : 1,
  'C' : 2
  'A' : 3,
};
```

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628713

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort map's values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628713/how-to-sort-maps-values)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This example uses a custom compare function which makes `sort()` sort the keys by value. Then the keys and values are inserted into a `LinkedHashMap` because this kind of map guarantees to preserve the order.
Basically the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/29629447/217408 but customized to your use case.

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  var temp= { 
    'A' : 3,
    'B' : 1,
    'C' : 2
  };

  var sortedKeys = temp.keys.toList(growable:false)
    ..sort((k1, k2) => temp[k1].compareTo(temp[k2]));
    LinkedHashMap sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap
      .fromIterable(sortedKeys, key: (k) => k, value: (k) => temp[k]);
  print(sortedMap);
}
```

Try it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/4c97cdb1d2cb7b48ade4)

Comment: I'm just getting started with Dart and I also needed this solution/pattern for my project, but the [Dart](https://dartlang.org) website does not explain this concept. Can you point me to a book or website that explains this and other concepts?

Comment: I don't know a book or website where this would be explained.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is it possible to sort this descending order? And after that would it be possible to get the the top 3 values? Be it in ascending or descending? How would one get the top 3 largest value keys? Thanks

Comment: To reverse the order swap `k1` and `k2` in `..sort(...)`. To get the top 3 use `var sortedKeys = temp.keys.toList(growable:false)
    ..sort((k1, k2) => temp[k2].compareTo(temp[k1])).take(3);` The LinkedHashMap.fromIterable(...)` will then build the map only from these keys.

Comment: Many thanks @GünterZöchbauer, but I am getting this error when using the suggested ``take(3)``: ``This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.``. The Map I want to sort is of type: ``Map<String, double>``

Comment: Sorry, that's because `..`. Move `.take(3)` to `LinkedHashMap sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap
      .fromIterable(sortedKeys.take(3), key: ...`

Answer (score 8):

The [SplayTreeMap](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.0/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html) has a named constructor which accepts map and a comparator which is used to sort given map while building new map. Since SplayTreeMap is a descendant of Map you can easily substitute it.

```
import 'dart:collection';
void main() {
  var unsorted = {'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 2};
  final sorted = SplayTreeMap.from(
    unsorted, (key1, key2) => unsorted[key1].compareTo(unsorted[key2]));
  print(sorted);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution loss information if 2 values are the same.
try with : `{'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 2}` which will return `{B: 2, A: 3}` (C key is lost)

Answer (score 2):

Dart version 2.3.0+ now [recommends](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_for_elements_to_map_fromIterable.html) to use 'for' elements when building maps from iterables. And you won't need `collection:dart`

```
var temp= { 
  'A' : 3,
  'B' : 1,
  'C' : 2
};

final sorted = temp.entries.toList()..sort((a, b)=> a.value.compareTo(b.value));
temp = {for (var entry in sorted) entry.key: entry.value};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
final Map<String, ClassCategory> category;
...

Map<String, ClassCategory> sorted = SplayTreeMap.from(category,
    (key1, key2) => category[key1]!.title.compareTo(category[key2]!.title));

for (var item in sorted.entries) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).