# HashMap no instance key

Tags: dart, hashmap, key

What is wrong with my code?

`widget.woList` is this datatype `List<HashMap<int, ABC>>()`

```
for (var i in widget.woList) {
  print(i.toString());
}
```

By printing above code, I get

```
  {5838: ABC(pid: 84201,userId: 545)}
```

But when I want to get only key ( `print(i.key.toString());`), I get below error:

```
Class '_HashMap<int, ABC>' has no instance getter 'key'.
Receiver: Instance of '_HashMap<int, ABC>'
Tried calling: key
```

Comment: The name is `keys` if you want to list all keys of the Map: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/Map/keys.html

Comment: And if you know there are only one key in the map you can do: `i.keys.first.toString()`.

Comment: @julemand101 thanks! can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556012/compare-list-hashmap-inside-listview

Comment: I am not a Flutter developer and your other question is quite a mess where it is not clear what you want and what you have. So no, I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analyzer should give an error in your case since a `Map` does not contain any property with the name `key`. Instead the name is `keys` which return a Iterable of keys in the map:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/Map/keys.html

A map can contain multiple keys but if you know there are only one key in the map you can do something like: `i.keys.first.toString()`. But if there are multiple keys you need to loop through them.

I will recommend you use auto completion in your IDE when programming in Dart and make use of the analyzer. By using the tools the SDK provides, it is much easier to browse what properties and methods there are in each class together with the documentation. And since Dart can figure out the type of lots of variables automatically, you can use the IDE to also identify the type of each variable without even running the program.

Comment: do you know how to sort a hashMap based on values?

Comment: HashMap is unordered "Iterating the map's keys, values or entries (through forEach) may happen in any order. The iteration order only changes when the map is modified": https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-collection/HashMap-class.html

Comment: Do you mean how to iterate over the keys in the map in an ordered way? Because that is possible if you get the keys as a List with `keys.toList()` and call `sort()` on this list and use the sorted list to iterate when getting the values from the map.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to loop through the HashMap as well:

```dart
for (HashMap<int, ABC> i in list) {
  i.forEach((key, value) {
    print(key.toString());
    print(value.toString());
  });
}
```

Make sure you typo the "i" variable in the for with `HashMap<int, ABC>` to get autocompletes from your IDE.

Comment: do you know how to sort a hashMap based on values?

Comment: Take a look to [How to sort map value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620546/how-to-sort-map-value)