# How can I know what is the most sold product of a list? flutter-dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of items from the orders by date, so based on its quantity I want to find what is the most sold product.

This is the class for my items

```
class CartItem{
  String id;
  String name;
  String image;
  int quantity;
  double price;

  CartItem({
  this.id,
  this.name,
  this.image,
  this.quantity,
  this.price,
  });
}
```

For example:

```
List<CartItem> list = orders.products;

list.forEach((element => print('${element.name} : ${element.quantity)');
```

It will print:

```
Dress : 1
Boots : 2
Trousers : 3
Dress : 2
Trousers : 2
```

So based on this example, how can I get the most sold product which is 'Trousers' and the sum of its quantity which is 5 for this case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another example:

```
// Dart 2.6.1 

main() {
  List list = [
    {
      "name":"Dress",
      "quantity" : 1
    },{
      "name":"Boots",
      "quantity" : 2
    },{
      "name":"Trousers",
      "quantity" : 3
    },{
      "name":"Dress",
      "quantity" : 2
    },{
      "name":"Trousers",
      "quantity" : 2
    }
  ];


  var products={

  };

  String mostSelling="";
  int quantity=0;

  list.forEach((e) {

    if(products[e["name"]]== null){
      products[e["name"]]= e["quantity"];
    } else {
     products[e["name"]]+= e["quantity"];
    }

    if(products[e["name"]] >quantity){
      mostSelling=  e["name"];
      quantity = products[e["name"]];
      }
   }
  );


  print("$mostSelling : $quantity");
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm, all I had to do was to transform my list to a map. However I have a question, what if by any chance there are for example 5 Dresses and 5 Trousers?

Answer (score 1):

You can covert the list to a map so you can see distinct items in the list. but rather than assigning the value to the key, if the key already exists, add the value

as:

```
list.forEach((item) => {
  map2[item.name] = item.quantity + (map2[item.name] ?? 0)
});
```

you will get the output:

```
{Dress: 3, Boots: 2, Trousers: 5}
```

then finally you can sort the map like this:

```
var sortedKeys = map2.keys.toList(growable:false)
    ..sort((k1, k2) => map2[k2].compareTo(map2[k1]));
    LinkedHashMap sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap
      .fromIterable(sortedKeys, key: (k) => k, value: (k) => map2[k]);
  print(sortedMap);
```

sorting os mentioned here as well [How to sort map value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620546/how-to-sort-map-value)

then you can get the first element which is the product with the highest orders

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think this seems a little bit complex for a begginer like me, I mean, I still don't understand how to get the highest number from that sorted map, should I print the last position?, how?. Thanks again man.

Comment: Oh, maybe transforming that sorted map back to list.

Comment: yes that is also an option, but I think the answer servers the purpose well! cheers!